How do I implement x-consistent-hash-exchange using Spring XML
All other exchange types are declared in http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit schema, but couldn't find x-consistent-hash-exchange in it. Where is it defined?
I tried implementing consistent hash exchange in XML, however, this is the exception I got after trying to use if from rabbit schema:

Exception in thread "main"
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
Line 64 in XML document from URL [file:/conf/spring/mq-admin.xml] is
invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
lineNumber: 64; columnNumber: 84; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching
wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element
'rabbit:x-consistent-hash-exchange'


That's true, there is no custom XML tag for the ConsistentHashExchange.
All those headers in the end declare some bean definitions.
For this one it is simply enough to do like this:
<beans:bean id="myConsistentHashExchange" class="org.springframework.amqp.core.ConsistentHashExchange">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="name" value="myConsistentHashExchange"/>
    <beans:property name="hashHeader" value="myHashHeader"/>
</beans:bean>

We don't have plans to extend XML support.
UPDATE
For versions before 3.2, we have to use a CustomExchange for bean definition:
<beans:bean id="myConsistentHashExchange" class="org.springframework.amqp.core.CustomExchange">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="name" value="myConsistentHashExchange"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="type" value="x-consistent-hash"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="durable" value="true"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="autoDelete" value="true"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="arguments">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="hash-header" value="myHashHeader"/>
        </beans:map>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

And the result is like this:

NOTE: The rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange plugin has to be enabled on the broker: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/tree/main/deps/rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange

Tried this solution, but got error as - Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rabbitConnectionFactoryBean'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.amqp.core.ConsistentHashExchange] for bean with name 'myConsistentHashExchange' defined in URL [file:]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.amqp.core.ConsistentHashExchange

Also tried using org.springframework.amqp.core.CustomExchange instead of org.springframework.amqp.core.ConsistentHashExchange. That didn't give any error but didn't create the exchange either

Yeah... OK. So, looks like you are trying to use a new feature which is available only in the latest milestone: https://spring.io/blog/2024/07/15/spring-amqp-3-2-0-m1-available.

See an UPDATE in my answer.
